# Convert PHP mcrypt_decrypt in a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, mcrypt

I'm doing an analysis of an old MySQL database. In it, some of the column types are of blob type.
When I checked the front end (written in PHP), apparently those blobs were being decoded using this method when being showed on the frontend:

> $crypttext = $this->safe_b64decode($value); 
> $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
> $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
> $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
> return trim($decrypttext);

I'm trying to do a select statement against the column and get the decryptedtext in my query.

Any idea of how to do it ?

Thank you

P.S. I have the $key value as well

Comment: Mcrypt is dead and gone, and for good reason. Also Mcrypt's Rijndael implementation is more or less specific to Mcrypt. You can use [phpseclib/mcrypt_compat](https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat) as a stand-in for now, but you should convert your data to something more standard, eg: AES-256, that is supported by support libraries like OpenSSL. Also ECB is an awful cipher mode, you should avoid it where possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeh i hate mcrypt, but unfortunately it's a legacy i have to work with. So at the moment i just want to decode whatever is in the database